# How Can i add a "AddNew" button at the end of drop downs in a Custom ComboBox Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a custom control with a ComboBox. I want to add a button at the end of the drop-down list that says "AddNew," such as "AddNewStudent," which, when clicked, opens a form to register a new student.

Since I expect to create many instances of the custom control, some of which may not need this feature, I want it to be activatable and vice versa. For instance, a ComboBox that lists students' grades doesn't need this feature because the grades are something known and unchanging. Additionally, I want the actions taken when the "AddNew" button is clicked to be a user-settable dependency property since the actions taken when the "AddNew" button is clicked will be different for each instance.

[Here is the repos on github of the Example below](https://github.com/MeshkaM/FloatingLabelComboBox)

[image: My Example to use]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look at your source codes.
I’ll just suggest one of the simple typical approaches to implement the logic you need (if, of course, I understood correctly what you need).

```cs
    public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> Ints { get; } = new() {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        public RelayCommand AddInt => GetCommand(()=> Ints.Add(Ints.Count));
    }
```

```xml
<Window ----------------------
        ----------------------
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddItemWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SomeViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="items">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Ints, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddInt, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource items}}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To add this logic to your Custom Control, you need to implement the ICommandSource interface in it for the user to connect external commands. And add another Dependency Property to control the visibility of the button in the ComboBox list.
It also makes sense to add Dependency Properties to change the appearance of this button: Content, ContentTemplate, Style, etc.

But personally, I don’t see much point in this, since this button can be added to the list very simply at the place where your Custom Control is used, as I showed above.

You can then customize a button (or any other element) in a very varied and simple way. Without an additional whole bunch of Dependency Property, which will be necessary if this is done in the internal logic of Custom Control.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, while i am yet to implement the way you recommeded, i want to ask you how i can implement that into my custom Control, will it be putting in inside the ComboBox as a DataTamplate in the Style of the CustomContol?

Comment: @Moha It all depends on how customizable you want to make this list item. It can be just a button with text, it can be a button with any content, it can be any UI element or other object. It is necessary to configure its visualization with styles, templates, triggers, etc. It should move when the list is scrolled or remain in place. I cannot answer these questions for you. The complication can be continued ad infinitum. You yourself must decide where to stop this complication.

Comment: @Moha I was unable to run the code from your repository. An exception is thrown. Most likely due to the lack of "SQL Server". Can you change your code so that some kind of test collection is used instead of the DB? Or use SQLite so that the cloned repository can be executed immediately.

Comment: OK i will try SQLite

Comment: In my opinion, your idea with a control combining Label and ComboBox is very unsuccessful.
At a minimum, it should be derived from ComboBox, and not from Control. Label should be changed to TextBlock.

Comment: Send me (EldHasp) an invitation coloboration. So that I can send you the changes.

Comment: OK, i have inivited you, please check it

Comment: Thanks for the issue. "TextBlock Is lightweight and performs better in most cases". I think that is what you are pointing to.

Comment: I accepted the invitation.

Comment: I can't understand one more thing. You are using MaterialDesign. This package already implements the HintAssist view you need. I can’t understand why you are creating your own equivalent of what already exists?

Comment: Thanks for the issue but i didn't see any HintAssist in WPF except material design package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256436/discussion-between-moha-and-eldhasp).

Comment: There is a lot that needs to be changed in your solution. Therefore, we will add changes in stages. Check out the new commit in the eldhasp branch. Added basic implementations of ViewModel and Commands. The ability to work without a database has been added to DAL.